# Cannot get the Titles in my PAGER TITLE STRIP for a view pager

Tags: android

My MAIN ACTIVITY is :

```
    public class UpperBody extends FragmentActivity {
    ViewPager viewPager=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.upper_body);
        viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(fragmentManager));
    }
}
class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment=null;
        if(position==0){
            fragment=new Chest();
        }
        if(position==1){
            fragment=new Shoulder();
        }
        if(position==2){
            fragment=new Back();
        }
        if(position==3){
            fragment=new Biceps();
        }
        if(position==4){
            fragment=new Triceps();
        }
        return fragment;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 5;
    }
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        if(position==0){
            return "CHEST";
        }
        if(position==1){
            return "SHOULDER";
        }
        if(position==2){
            return "BACK";
        }
        if(position==3){
            return "BICEPS";
        }
        if(position==4){
            return "TRICEPS";
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

XML file is :

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:background="#33B5E5"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp">

    </android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip>
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

The above operations are functional but the Page Titles above various Fragments are not visible.
Can anyone please explain what is the reason behind this.
Actually I am new to ANDROID.
HELP!