# Cannot set my Edittext value with change in my spinner selection

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-spinner

I am building an application in which i added a spinner where the user is supposed to select the month and with respect to change in month the edittext field also changes. I made a code by my side but it is not working also not showing any error.
My code is :

```
public class NewMemberRegister extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner spinner4;
EditText e1;
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_member_register);
        spinner4=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        ArrayAdapter adapter3
=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.period,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner4.setAdapter(adapter3);
        spinner4.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
}
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        String str= parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);
        if (spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==0){
            e1.setText(" ");
       }else if(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==1){
            e1.setText("100");
        }else if(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==2){
            e1.setText("1500");
        }else if(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==3){
            e1.setText("3500");
        }else if(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==4){
            e1.setText("6000");
        }else if(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==5){
            e1.setText("10000");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
```

Any Ideas for this?...Comments are Welcome !

Comment: try using only `if` statement instead of `else if` and check if it works?

Comment: Show what value from that: `spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: and also why are you registering  e1=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.amount);  onItemSelected each time, register one time in onCreate and you are good

Comment: also show R.array.period period values

Comment: Problem is resolved with : spinner4.getSelectItemPosition()==0

Comment: If anyone can try to solve this,then it would be really helpful...i am giving link of my another question... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913837/cannot-get-the-titles-in-my-pager-title-strip-for-a-view-pager

Comment: you can try this demo also : http://sampleprogramz.com/android/editspinner.php

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
if (spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position)==0){

}else
  ..
```

Causing issue. because comparing non `Integer` type  to `int` value.

As see here:
[AdapterView.getItemAtPosition(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getItemAtPosition(int)) : method takes index of item as `int` but return `Object` type value instead of `int`.

So use `Integer.parseInt` to get `int`  representing of Object which is returned from `getItemAtPosition` before comparing it:

```
if (Integer.parseInt(spinner4.getItemAtPosition(position).toString())==0){
            e1.setText(" ");
}else
   .....
```

Do same for other conditions.